# How to set full width to a specific HTML element in DOMPDF

Tags: php, html, css, pdf, dompdf

I'm using DOMPDF to generate a pdf file in php program, here is may code to generate the pdf :

```
  public static function generatePDF()
    {
        $pdf = App::make('dompdf.wrapper');
        //$pdf->setPaper('A4','landscape');
        $pdf->loadView('pdfview');
        return $pdf->download('Report.pdf');
    }
```

in my pdfview, I have a HTML element with properti like this :

```
<div style="background-color: #353535; max-width:100%; margin:0; padding:0" >
...
...
...
</div>
```

As we can see, the width is full and there is also not margin or padding, but the pdf result is a little bit different like this :
[image]

So How do I make this div element fills the entire pdf width ? 
Thank you so much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this :

```
    <style>
      @page {
        size: a4 landscape; 
        margin:0.9;padding:0.9; // you can set margin and padding 0 
      } 
      body {
        font-family: Times New Roman;
        font-size: 33px;
        text-align: center;
        border: thin solid black;  
      }
    </style>
```

Comment: Coool.. Thanks... It works.. But for me, I don't need to change the size to A4 landscape.. :)
Thanks btw Mr. Roma.. :D

Comment: eeeh...btw.. Where did you get that info Mr. @Roma ? Would you like to share your source to me.. ? :)
Thanks a lot.. :)

Comment: I came to know about it from here :-> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30386157/dompdf-landscape-output-is-messed-up

Comment: Cool... Thanks Mr. @Roma... B-)